# Printing a file in form of a booklet

Tags: printing

I want to take print outs of around 12 pages in the form of a booklet half the size of an A4 sheet.

Right now I am taking prints on both sides and two pages per sheet. However in the default configuration, my printer prints pages 1 and 2 on one side of the sheet and pages 3 and 4 on the other.

Instead I want that it prints pages 1 and 3 on one side and pages 2 and 4 on the other, so that I can cut the sheet from the middle and stack two pieces over each other to get something in a form of booklet.

There are many options available in the printer but I don't want to waste paper just by experimenting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problems some years ago. I could help me by using Microsoft Words printer settings and "odd / even" Page print > Duplex. But also there is a better way for you.

Try use some "Printer drivers" to create books. I've searched something and found these links:
http://bookletcreator.com

http://www.chip.de/downloads/Buchdruck-0.1b_13012107.html

Hope it helps